# Can this Go code be refactored?

Tags: go

Using only 1 'if' statement and no 'else' & no switch & no shorthand notation for if-else?

```
    // Original function
    func Wheel(WheelPos uint32) {
        if WheelPos < 85 {
            fmt.Println("WheelPos < 85",Color(WheelPos*3, 255-WheelPos*3, 0))
        } else if WheelPos < 170 {
            WheelPos -= 85
            fmt.Println("WheelPos >= 85",Color(0, WheelPos*3, 255-WheelPos*3))
        } else {
            WheelPos -= 170
            fmt.Println("WheelPos > 170",Color(0, 255-WheelPos*3, WheelPos*3))
        }
    }
```

The above function is called in the main inside a for loop like so:

```
    func main() {
        var i uint32
        for i = 0; i < 255; i++ {
            Wheel(i)
        }
    }
```

The Color function is defined as such:

```
    func Color(r uint32, g uint32, b uint32) uint32 {
        return (r << 16) | (g << 8) | b
    }
```

I have started off with something like so:

```
    func Wheel(WheelPos uint32) {
        if (WheelPos < 85) || (WheelPos >= 85) || (WheelPos > 170) {
         // logic....
        }
    }
```

Comment: If you are looking for a feedback for your code, you can try http://codereview.stackexchange.com/

Comment: No no, I wasn't looking for a code review. Thanks though. I wanted to know if the alternative way I thought up was possible or not and if yes, how do I do it?

Comment: Thank's guys. This question can be closed.

Answer (score 1):

I don't see how you would refactor the code, and somehow keep it clear and expressive enough.

If you have only three cases to consider, making them in three separate if/else is the easiest way to code those cases.

Comment: using [`switch`](http://play.golang.org/p/aKpIibzLyI) might be considered cleaner but yeah this question is way too opinion based.

Answer (score 0):

It is technically possible: you could create an if statement for the `>170` case, then define an array of 170 function pointers and use an index operation for the other two cases. I can't think of a reasonable case where this solution is actually better than the one you already have though.